# What is the point of a nil AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer in a Swift closure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, closures

I was reading the different ways to parse REST API calls in Swift and came across the following:

```
var url : String = "http://google.com?test=toto&test2=titi"
var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
    let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

    if (jsonResult != nil) {
        // process jsonResult
    } else {
       // couldn't load JSON, look at error
    }


})
```

The one line that makes no sense to me is `var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil`. We already captured our `NSError` parameter and stored it in a variable called `error`, and now we're overwriting that and making it nil in our first line in the closure? Or if somehow Swift then performs a downcast of the error from type `NSError!` to `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?>`, then can someone explain how that happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer is the equivalent to NSError** in Objective-C, which is used in methods as an inout expression. The syntax looks very strange.

The most reliable way is to consider both errors and define a second error variable. As GET is the default HTTP method of NSURLRequest, an immutable request is sufficient.

```
let url = "http://google.com?test=toto&test2=titi"
let request = NSURLRequest(URL:  NSURL(string: url)!)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

  if error != nil {
    // handle NSURLConnection error
  } else {
    var jsonError : NSError?
    if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary {
      // process jsonResult

    } else {
      // couldn't load JSON, look at jsonError
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So what was all that about setting the `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` to nil?

Comment: this is for reusing the error pointer returned from the connection request

Comment: How come we don't just create another variable to do that? In the code from my question, we go directly into JSON Serialization before we even check to see if there was an error stored.

Comment: yes, it's pretty error-prone. That's why I changed it in my solution

Comment: I guess the intention of the original code is: If the connection fails the serialization will fail anyway but the connection error reason information gets lost